# Como puedo evitar abrir un User Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando en una app windows forms. Al momento de llamar a un user control si esta abierto que ya no lo vuelva a llamar.
Quiero hacer algo como esto:

```
public static Boolean OpenForm(Form Formulario)
    {
        Form F = Application.OpenForms[Formulario.Name];
        if (F == null) return false;

        if (F.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            F.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        F.Focus();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partamos de la base que los `user control` no se abren, se instancian.

Además estos se ubican dentro de un contenedor ya ser un Panel, por lo tanto podrías validar la lista de `Controls` del contenedor para ver si ya existe.

```
bool existe = Panel1.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().Any();

if(!existe){
     UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
     Panel1.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```